# Guice and Play2 Singleton from trait

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, guice

I am using Play with Scala and I am trying to create a singleton, and i want to inject it from its trait and not directly.

for example:

```
@ImplementedBy(classOf[S3RepositoryImpl])
trait S3Repository {
}
@Singleton
class S3RepositoryImpl extends S3Repository {
}
```

But this fails with error:

> trait Singleton is abstract; cannot be instantiated

I have tried several combinations and they all produce the same.

I come from Spring background and its very natural there? am i missing something about how Guice handles this type of Injection?

Thanks.

Comment: Does it works if you remove the `@Singleton` annotation? Also, could you please post the complete stacktrace?

Comment: yes it does, but thats not a singleton

Comment: Weird. Can you also post the code for your `Module`?

Comment: `import javax.inject.Singleton`

Answer (score 41):

As pointed out by @Tavian-Barnes, the solution is to ensure you have the following import:

```
import javax.inject.Singleton
```

Comment: OMG, this saves lives. Exactly the missing piece.

Answer (score 6):

I have here a "complete" working example, just hope that I'm not stating the obvious...

```
package controllers

import play.api._
import play.api.mvc._
import com.google.inject._

class Application @Inject() (s3: S3Repository) extends Controller {
  def index = Action {
    println(s3.get)
    Ok
  }
}

@ImplementedBy(classOf[S3RepositoryImpl])
trait S3Repository {
  def get: String
}

@Singleton
class S3RepositoryImpl extends S3Repository {
  def get: String = "bla"
}
```

Whenever you mark a class' constructor with `@Inject` the Guice will manage the injection of the instance itself. So, if you marked your class as `@Singleton`, Guice will create and will always give you just that one instance. Nobody can stop you from manually instantiating a class in your code... You can explore it in detail at [Play](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaDependencyInjection#Singletons).

Comment: funny thing is that when you replace in your working example `import com.google.inject._` with `import com.google.inject.{ImplementedBy, Inject}` the problem sticks. probably there are more stuff to import to make this magic work, too bad the compile error message is unclear

Comment: No idea why, it should be enough to import just `com.google.inject.{ImplementedBy, Inject, Singleton}`. Because those are Java annotations, there is no Scala implicits magic or such...

Answer (score 4):

Use below import, instead of `import javax.inject.Singleton`

```
import com.google.inject.{Inject, Singleton}
```

Answer (score 2):

Import both Inject and Singleton.

```
import javax.inject.{Inject, Singleton}
```

Refrain from using:

```
import com.google.inject.{Inject, Singleton}
```

as play framework requires the javax import